# Написать функцию, которая возвращает список интерфейсов, преобразуя указанный при запуске скрипта параметр

Tags: python

Нужно написать функцию, которая получает строку вида "1,5,6-10,Po25-Po30" и возвращает список, в котором содержится элементы Eth1,Eth5,Eth6,Eth7...Eth10,Po25,Po26...Po30, т.е к каждому числу подставляется Eth и если есть диапазоны, то они раскрываются.
Пример моего кода ниже. Но что-то мне он не сильно нравится, полагаю что можно сделать как-то удачнее.

```
interface_list = sys.argv[2].split(",")
def create_interface_list(interface_list):
"""
Преобразуем список, переданной в командной строке, в список интерфейсов
"""
updated_list = []
for intf in interface_list:
    if '-' not in intf:
        if 'Po'  in intf:
            updated_list.append(intf)
        else:
            if not is_arista:
                updated_list.append(f'Eth1/{str(intf)}')
            else:
                updated_list.append(f'Et/{str(intf)}')
    else: #Если указан диапазон портов, то преобразуем его в список 
        if 'Po' in intf:
            intf = intf.replace('Po', '')
            int_range = list(range(int(intf.split('-')[0]), (int(intf.split('-')[1])+1)))
            for number in int_range:
                updated_list.append(f'Po{str(number)}')
        elif 'Po' not in intf:
            int_range = list(range(int(intf.split('-')[0]), (int(intf.split('-')[1])+1)))
            for number in int_range:
                if not is_arista:
                    updated_list.append(f'Eth1/{str(number)}')
                else:
                    updated_list.append(f'Et{str(number)}')
return updated_list
```

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: В одну строчку: `func = lambda s: [f"{p if p else 'Eth'}{i}" for p,a,b in map(lambda x: __import__("re").findall(r"(\D+)?(\d+)-(?:\D+)?(\d+)", f"{x}-{x}")[0], s.split(",")) for i in range(int(a), int(b)+1)]`

Comment: MaxU, добавил свой код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбор диапазона регулярным выражением покомпактнее будет...

```
import re

def create_interface_list(interface_list):
    """
    Преобразуем список, переданной в командной строке, в список интерфейсов
    """
    updated_list = []
    for intf in interface_list:
        prefix, start, end = re.findall(r"(\D+)?(\d+)-(?:\D+)?(\d+)", f"{intf}-{intf}")[0]
        if not prefix:
            prefix = 'Et/' if is_arista else 'Eth1/'
        updated_list.extend(map(f'{prefix}{{}}'.format, range(int(start), int(end)+1)))

    return updated_list
```

Comment: Выглядит получше. 
Не могли бы пояснить, как работает updated_list.extend(map(f'{prefix}{{}}'.format, range(int(start), int(end)+1))) ? А именно то, что внутри map

Comment: @VladimirFomin Внутри map f-строка, в которую подставляется префикс. Ну а двойные фигурные скобки становятся одинарными (т.е. после подстановки там будет что-то типа "Eth1/{}"), чтобы туда уже format подставил значение (которое ему передаст map при итерации по range(...).

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку это видимо учебное задание, вместо кода дам алгоритм:

- разбиваете ввод по знаку `,`
- смотрите, есть ли в очередном элементе знак `-`, если есть разбиваете на два элемента, берёте из них цифры и делаете цикл по `range(от, до+1)`, только запоминаете ещё, что там впереди до цифр какие символы, оно ещё пригодится
- дальше каждый элемент либо ввода либо цикла смотрите у него первый символ цифра или нет, если нет, то добавляете в выходной список как есть, а если цифра, то спереди добавляете `Eth` перед цифрой ещё
- делаете `','.join(выходной_список)`

Ну, это почти всё, только с циклами по диапазону будет немного сложнее, советую на отдельные функции код разбить и скомбинировать их.

Comment: Как в моем случае было бы разумно разбить этот код? И нужно ли это делать? (код добавил )

Answer (score 0):

Решение без использования регулярок по алгоритму [@CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1368172/457260):

```
strn = "1,5,6-10,Po25-Po30"

res = []
for i in strn.split(','):
    a,_,b = i.partition('-')
    if a.isnumeric():
        res += [f'Eth{n}' for n in range(int(a), int(b)+1 if b else int(a)+1)]
    else:
        suf = a.strip('0123456789')
        res += [f'{suf}{n}' for n in range(int(a.strip(suf)), int(b.strip(suf))+1)]
print(res)

'''
['Eth1', 'Eth5', 'Eth6', 'Eth7', 'Eth8', 'Eth9', 'Eth10', 
 'Po25', 'Po26', 'Po27', 'Po28', 'Po29', 'Po30']
```